# Asynchronous messaging (ActiveMQ, MSMQ) to ASP application (MVC3)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asynchronous, msmq, message-queue, activemq-classic

I have been reading articles about asynchronous messaging between clients using MVC3 and the SignalR library (http://sergiotapia.com/2011/09/signalr-with-mvc3-chat-app-build-asynchronous-real-time-persistant-connection-websites/)

We currently use activemq for some of our fat client apps and use topics to broadcast data to everyone. Does anyone know if this sort of thing could be used in MVC3 as well?

I'd like to create an application that doesn't require a user to install anything (and could even be used on a phone), but it would be monitoring continuously-changing data. We're talking refreshing data every 2-3 seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have asynchronous messaging with client (browser) use SignalR. ActiveMQ and MSMQ are technologies for thick clients and server-to-server communication. They require installation (MSMQ requires windows installation) and they are not accessible from browser (well I can imagine accessing MSMQ through ActiveX or ActiveMQ from Java applet but that is not what you are looking for).

Comment: I guess I don't know what the limitations are on SignalR messaging vs. ActiveMQ. It feels so weird to have it all hitting a web server rather than an explicit service. Coming from someone who has worked exclusively with full .net desktop apps and windows services, I don't quite know the pitfalls of web applications yet.

Comment: Just pointing out that ActiveMQ has a REST API suitable for JavaScript http://activemq.apache.org/rest.html

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible ways to go is to build a web service which will implement communication with AMQ/MSMQ via their APIs and do poll this web service from your webpage (via ajax call for example) to refresh the data as it's needed.